# How would i use Jquery to select inline property width value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having difficulty in selecting the "style=:width: 10%" value in jquery for progressbar element in bootstrap.

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%;"> <span class="sr-only">0% Complete</span> </div>
```

This is what I have tried so far, `$(".progress-bar[style*=width]");` but it returns the entire div.

My goal is to target that value and change it via Ajax.

Here is a [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yth4Lq02/) boilerplate for your reference.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly would you target a value, and change it with ajax, the code you've posted is supposed to return the entire element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following.

**Get width**

```
var width = $(".progress-bar")[0].style.width;
```

**Set width**

```
$(".progress-bar")[0].style.width = '90%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a filter instead.  Try not to use attributes(other than id and class) as selectors.

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%;">
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$('.progress-bar').filter(function(){ return $(this).css('width') === "10%"; });
```

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/ has some notes about this mentioning concerns with certain selectors being potentially slower.  Something worth reviewing.